# Flutter - CachedNetworkImage -The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm getting data from firebase and there's an exception throwing.

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following ArgumentError was thrown resolving an image codec:
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2694:9)
#1      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2591:7)
#2      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:57:38)
#3      HttpFileService.get (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/file_service.dart:35:44)
#4      WebHelper._download (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/web_helper.dart:121:24)
#5      WebHelper._updateFile (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/web_helper.dart:103:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      WebHelper._downloadOrAddToQueue (package:flutter_cache_manager/src/web/web_helper.dart:71:7)
<asynchronous suspension>

Image provider: CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0)
 Image key: CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0):
  CachedNetworkImageProvider("", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

And here's my code

```
class _IMInventoryDetailsState extends State<IMInventoryDetails> {
  String fishImage = '';

  getFishData() async {
    DocumentSnapshot docc = await services.fish
        .doc(widget.boatOwnerInventoryData['fishType'])
        .get();
    setState(() {
      fishImage = docc['fishImage'];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getFishData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 250,
          color: Colors.grey[400],
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: fishImage,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Image is showing well but there's an exception...

And I do the same in different way.

i.e

```
class _IMInventoryDetailsState extends State<IMInventoryDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 150,
          width: 250,
          color: Colors.grey[400],
          child: FishD(fishName: widget.boatOwnerInventoryData['fishType']),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FishD extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? fishName;

  const FishD({Key? key, this.fishName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final FirebaseServices services = FirebaseServices();

    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: services.fish.doc(fishName).snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const SizedBox(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          );
        }

        return CachedNetworkImage(
          imageUrl: snapshot.data!['fishImage'],
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

No exceptions are throwing.

Why is my 1st method throwing an exception?

I did 1st method because I can reuse assigned variables for future purposes.
Actually, in here I don't need it but why is this go wrong?

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It's because you initialized your fishImage with an empty String at first. The first time the widget run build(), the setState function is not run yet, so the fishImage is still empty. CachedNetworkImage then receives an empty string as imageUrl and then throw an exception

Comment: But I added my function in initstate. So what is the matter? @DungNgo

Comment: You flow is currently like this: initState() -> getFishData() -> start async,await -> build() (error right here, since the async, await is not finished, hence the setState doesn't run and CachedNetworkImage receives an empty string) -> finish async, await, run setState() and re-trigger build()

Comment: okay thanks. so my 2nd method is the correct way of doing that?